# Programación paralela sobre matriz

Tags: java, c, hilos, matrices

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que necesito hacer cálculos sobre matrices de tamaños grandes. He hecho pruebas en Java con hilos, dividiendo la zona de la matriz que accede cada hilo, y resulta que tarda más que si lo hiciera recorriendo la matriz al completo. He probado disminuyendo y aumentando el número de hilos pero sigue pasando lo mismo. ¿saben por qué ocurre esto? ¿Se les ocurre alguna idea para resolver este problema? ¿Quizá cambiando el lenguaje?.

Comment: Sin ver un [mcve] de tu código, es imposible resonder a esta pregunta. Por favor trabaja en crear el ejemplo y edita tu pregunta para incluir el código del mismo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

La programación concurrente no es una solución mágica para cualquier cuestión de rendimiento; puede ser útil o no dependiendo de cual sea el problema.

Dos factores principales:

- Tamaño del problema: crear, inicializar y ejecutar los *threads* lleva tiempo. Los cambios de contexto también. Si el problema que intentas resolver es muy pequeño, la ventaja por usar *threads* puede no ser suficiente para compensar el coste de usarlas.
- Cuellos de botella/bloqueo. El uso de *threads* te permite no parar la ejecución porque un recurso este siendo utilizado. Por ejemplo, si un *thread* está esperando datos de la red o del disco duro, mientras el HW/SO se encarga de obtenerlos otro *thread* puede ejecutar su lógica en la CPU. Pero si todos los *threads* están limitados por el mismo recurso (en este caso sería CPU), todos los *threads* se limitarán mutuamente<sup>1</sup>.

A todo esto se añaden problemas a mucho más bajo nivel que también pueden aparecer (y que normalmente solo son estudiados en sistemas críticos o de tiempo real). Por ejemplo, el cambio de *threads* puede hacer que cambie lo que es la "localidad temporal" o "localidad espacial" del acceso a memoria y causar más fallos de caché, lo que hace el acceso a memoria mucho más lento.

En general, mi recomendación sería:

- Usar *threads* por defecto solo cuando la lógica lo necesite (p.ej. GUI separado del cálculo para evitar que se bloquee) o cuando el tipo de problema lo aconseje (p.ej. procesos que dependen mucho de acceso a la red).
- En cualquier otro tipo de problema, si quieres probar *threads* para ver si mejora el rendimiento, investigar y asegurarte de que efectivamente te son útiles.

Todo lo dicho arriba es independiente de que en un lenguaje un determinado programa se ejecute más o menos rápido que otro.

---

<sup>1</sup> Con procesadores *multithread* (todos hoy en día) se puede considerar que hacer *threads* distintos permite que se ejecuten en *cores* distintos sin interferirse por la CPU, pero no hay que olvidar que en la JVM hay otros *threads* y en el SO otros procesos que también compiten por esos *cores*.

Comment: Básicamente los que necesito es recorrer una matriz que representa una imagen pixel a pixel para aplicar alguna operación. He probado con CUDA en C pero parece que mi ordenador no lo soporta.

Answer (score 2):

Añado a la excelente respuesta de @SJuan76:

Cuando el problema es "limitado por CPU", es decir, la ejecución nunca está "detenida" esperando por una operación de entrada/salida o de red, sino que siempre está "consumiendo CPU" haciendo cálculos, como parece ser tu caso, usar *threads* sólo tiene sentido para poder aprovechar la existencia de varias CPUs.

Por tanto, si tu ordenador tiene cuatro cores, usar cuatro threads te permitiría usar los cuatro en paralelo. Pero más threads ya no tendria sentido pues en ese caso varios trhead competirían por la misma CPU y será imposible que notes ganancia alguna, y sí en cambio una ligera pérdida de rendimiento debido a los cambios de contexto que ese core debe realizar para pasar de un *thread* a otro.

Además de esto, si los *threads* están accediendo a la misma zona de memoria compartida, será necesario sincronizarles mediante cerrojos para evitar que dos *thread* intenten modificar la misma zona a la vez, o que un *thread* intente leer mientras otro está escribiendo. Estos cerrojos básicamente limitan el paralelismo incluso aunque dispongas de varios cores, pues lo que consiguen de hecho es que los cores "entren" a la zona protegida por el cerrojo por turnos, impidiendo que varios se ejecuten a la vez.

Si abusas de estos cerrojos cuando no son necesarios (por ejemplo, protegiendo el acceso a la matriz completa, cuando en realidad cada *thread* está trabajando sobre una zona independiente de la matriz y no habría problema en que lo hicieran en paralelo), estarás impidiendo el paralelismo. Sospecho que algo de esto debe de ocurrir en tu caso, aunque sin ver la implementación es imposible saberlo.

**Un ejemplo.** Imagina que el objetivo es contar cuantos ceros hay en la matriz. Un posible diseño sería que cada hilo reciba un trozo de la matriz sobre el cual trabajar y cuente cuántos ceros encuentra en él. Pero si decides que a medida que va encontrando ceros vaya actualizando una variable global, entonces ese diseño te planteará problemas.

En ese diseño el acceso a la variable global debe protegerse con cerrojo, pues de lo contrario dos hilos podrían intentar modificarla a la vez y perderse alguno de los incrementos (puesto que dos hilos podrían leer el valor del contador a la vez, sumarle uno a la vez, y volver a escribir el resultado, quedando el contador incrementado en uno en vez de dos).

Y si lo proteges con cerrojo, entonces estás limitando el paralelismo ya que cada vez que un hilo encuentra un cero y se dispone a incrementar el valor, puede encontrarse con otro hilo que lo está haciendo y debe esperar por él (además de la sobrecarga de "tomar" y "soltar" el cerrojo siempre, aún si no hay otros hilos accediendo al contador).

Un mejor enfoque a ese problema sería evitar la variable global. Cada hilo tiene su propio contador (variable local) sobre el que efectúa el recuento de ceros. No son necesarios cerrojos y el paralelismo se aprovecha bien. Pero después debes recoger el valor de contador encontrado por cada hilo y sumarlos todos.

Moraleja: el diseño multihilo que realices es crucial para determinar si vas a ganar algo o no. Intenta desacoplar lo más posible el trabajo de cada hilo y (repito) no crees más hilos que *cores* en tu sistema.